# Why are Enums not scaffolded unless you specify a Data Context

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, scaffold

When I scaffold a view from my model, my Enum is ignored unless a specify a Data Context Class? Why is this?

Here is my model:

```
 public class customer
{
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public Title customerTitle { get; set; }
    public string  CustomerName { get; set; }
}


public enum Title
{
    Mr, Miss, Mrs, Ms
}
```

When I scaffold a create view and specify a Data Context Class I get this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customerTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.customerTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customerTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I scaffold the same model again but without a Data Context the Enum isn't there at all.

This is where I do or do not specify a Data Context Class.

[image: Adding a View]

Comment: Please can you provide the different code, the code with the Data Context too so that we can see the difference in the code?

Comment: What was it that you have been scaffolding?

Comment: I was scaffolding a create view for the customers model

Comment: @Luke, I have added an image of where I am specifying the Data Context.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a lot more clear :)

Comment: Well, specifying a data context causes the scaffold to behave differently. That much is obvious. Apparently, one of those differences is that enum properties are included. The scaffold is the scaffold, though, so if it doesn't work the way you want it to, there's nothing you can do about that. In general, you should never rely on the scaffolding functionality, anyways. It's just training wheels. Once you know how things work, you're almost always better off just adding views and such manually.